# Need help in Reading Matching Array Strings from MongoDB

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I am using Mongo C APIs to implement DB Interface for a project.

MongoDB Document:

```
{
  _id,
  ...   // Some fields
  ...
  Array 
}
```

Query Used to Populate Values in the Array:

```
     BCON_APPEND (&query, "$push", "{",
                  "Array", "{", 
                  "Key", key,
                  "Value", (char*)value, "}",
                  "}");
```

Populated Array inside MongoDB:

```
"Array" : [ { "Key": "key1", "Value" : "string1" }, 
            { "Key": "key2", "Value" : "string2" },   
            { "Key": "key3", "Value" : "string3" },
          ]
```

Query used to find the matching row in the array:

```
 BCON_APPEND (&query, $elemMatch, 
              "Array", "{", "Key", key, 
              "}");
```

This query returns the complete document which contains a matching key in the array - which is fine.

Problem:

I am reading each field of the document returned by this query -- one by one.

When I encountered the Array field in the document -- my requirement is to get ONLY the matched row.

I tried to read the Array as follows:

```
   uint32_t          *document_len;
   const uint8_t    **document;

   bson_iter_recurse (&iter, &sub_iter)) 
   {
     while (bson_iter_next (&sub_iter)) 
     {
        bson_iter_document (sub_iter, 
                            &document_len,
                            document)
        // Suppose my "Key" was: "key2"
        // How to get the matching row: { "Key": "key2", "Value" : "string2" } as a String here ?
        // Also, I want to receive ONLY matching row -- & NOT all 3 rows
     }
   }
```

I am not able to read String from this Array and also, not able to get only the matching row -- not all 3 rows.

[Note: In while() loop above, If I put this trace:

```
 while (bson_iter_next (&sub_iter)) 
 {
      printf ("Found key \"%s\" in sub document.\n",
      bson_iter_key (&sub_iter));
 }
```

I get 3 prints:

```
  Found key 0 in sub document
  Found key 1 in sub document
  Found key 2 in sub document
```

So, it is clear that -- I am getting all values from the array and NOT the only matching one and I cannot retrieve the actual strings from the array]

References:

Mongo C APIs https://api.mongodb.org/c/current/

libbson https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_iter_t.html

Please help.

Comment: I think your problem lies in using mongo in a way it's not very good at helping you.  By Design,  MongoD is going to give you back the ENTIRE document that matches the query.  You're asking about the projection operator, but that'll only work if you switch your data model to {..."Array" : [ {"key1":"string1" }, ...]}.  How tied to the data model are you?

Comment: @dnlbmn: Thanks for your reply. It was required for my previous Mongo based project, I figured out the right projection myself